# While loop not working :(

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6_5 {
//
    static String studentName ="NO NAME";
    static int right = 0;
    static int number1=0;
    static int number2=0;
    static int answer=0;
    static double averageRight= 0.0;
    static int counter=0;

//The main function
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        inputName ();
        while (counter >=5) {
            getNumber();
            getAnswer ();
            checkAnswer ();
            counter= counter+1;
        }
        result ();
        displayInfo ();
    }

//
    public static String inputName (){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter student name: ");
        studentName = keyboard.next();
        return studentName;
    }
//
    public static int getNumber (){
        number1 =(int)((Math.random() * 500) + 1);
        number2 =(int)((Math.random() * 500) + 1);
        return number2;
    }
//
    public static int getAnswer (){
        System.out.println ("What is the answer to the following equation: ");
        System.out.print(+number1);
        System.out.print (" + ");
        System.out.println (+number2);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("What is the sum: ");
        answer = keyboard.nextInt ();
        return answer;
    }
//
    public static int checkAnswer (){
        if (number1 + number2 == answer) {
            System.out.println ("Right");
            right = right + 1;
        }
        else
            System.out.println ("Wrong");
        return right;
    }
//
    public static double result (){
        averageRight = right/5;
        return averageRight;
    }

    public static void displayInfo (){
        System.out.println ("Information for student: "+studentName);
        System.out.println ("The number right: "+right);
        System.out.println ("The average right is: " +averageRight);
    }

}
```

Here's my problem. This program is supposed to generate 5 random math equations and check the answers. After completion, it displays the results. The only problem is that it's not looping. After more than 6 hours I figured out that it is better to ask for help.

Comment: change to (Counter<=5 )

Answer (score 3):

The loop's condition - `while (counter >=5)` - is always false, since `counter` is initialized to 0.

change

```
while (counter >=5)
```

to

```
while (counter <=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that  `while (counter >=5)` is always `false` since the initial value is `0`.

Change to:

```
while (counter <=5)
```

Pay attention because you are using a class with all methods and fields static.
It is not a good way to use java.

Comment: Thanks; I'm still new to java at the moment I'm mostly learning by trial and error. My professor does helps but sometime it doesn't seem like he speaking in english.

Answer (score 0):

Change while (counter >=5) with while (counter <=5)

Answer (score 0):

while (counter <=5)

Your condition is not correct. Please correct it.